# SwiftUI macOS build app to install it on another mac

Tags: swift, macos, build, swiftui

After i have created my app in `swift ui` how do i create the file so i can try it on another pc mac?

I've searched but can't find a tutorial explaining how I can create a `macOS` app.

Comment: Menu "Product > Archive"

Comment: If you'd install your app on a different machine without a big warning alert from the system. Make sure you sign and notarize the build before distribution

Comment: @Asperi: I did as indicated, `Copy app` distribution method.
The file is saved on the desktop, when I open it it gives me an error, the error report appears to send it to apple.

Comment: @NghiaTran: I tried it on the same pc where it was built.

Comment: Ok, maybe I solved it.

Comment: Now I have to figure out how after creating the build, how can I make it happen as an installation.
So even if I restart the pc, it starts when it starts.
But for this I open another question.
Thx.